# Trying to return the amount of "Three of a kind" in a poker hand that run 16000 times

Tags: c++

```
bool Hand::isFlush()
{
    if(cardVector[0].suit=cardVector[1].suit=cardVector[2].suit=cardVector[3].suit=cardVector[4].suit)return true;
    return false;
}

bool Hand :: isThreeOfKind() 

{


        if (cardVector[4].rank=cardVector[3].rank, // comparing card 5 to 4, then card 5 to 3.
        cardVector[4].rank=cardVector[2].rank)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
         if (cardVector[3].rank=cardVector[2].rank, //comparing card 4 to 3 and the card 4 to 2
            cardVector[3].rank=cardVector[1].rank)
            {
                return true;
            }
         return false;
         if (cardVector[2].rank=cardVector[1].rank,
                    cardVector[2].rank=cardVector[0].rank) //comparing card 3 to 2 and the card 3 to 1
                 {
                        return true;
                 }      
        return false;}



int main ()
{

    cout<< "welcome" << endl;


    Deck deck;
    float flushCount=0;
    float threeKind=0;
    float count= 16000;
        for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
    {
        deck.shuffle();
        Hand hand=deck.dealHand();
        if(hand.isFlush())flushCount++;


    }
        for (int j=0;j<count;j++)
        {
            Hand hand=deck.dealHand();
            if (hand.isThreeOfKind())threeKind++;

        }
    cout << "The amount of flushes in a game run 160000 times is..."<< endl;
    cout << flushCount << endl;
    cout << (flushCount/count)*100 << endl;
    cout << " Your have this many  "<< threeKind << endl; 





    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

When I run the code I get the value of `threeKind` equal to the value of `count`. What I am trying to do is get the amount of three of kind in a hand of 5 cards. I feel like the logic in `Hand::isThreeOfKind()` may not be correct? I am trying to repeat what i did for `bool Hand::isFlush()`.

Comment: You are aware `isFlush`, as well as `isThreeOfKind`, is performing assignment, not comparisons? Also, you appear to not understand what the comma operator does.

Comment: Your code also seems to assume that the cards are in order, i.e. that three cards that are the same rank will be adjacent in the cardVector. The assignments-instead-of-equalitychecks are more grevious at the moment, though.

Comment: One way to do it is to sort the hand and search that way for contiguous cards.  Another is to have an array of all the ranks and count all of the cards that way and then look for any rank that has the value 3.  Doing it with a bunch of if/else gets really complicated and ugly looking fast.

Comment: Get it to work right on one set of five cards, before you try to loop across 16000 of them.

Comment: You'll also never test anything but the first check you have because you return false unconditionally if it fails.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is betrays a lack of effort to solve the problem before dumping it here. It is highly unlikely to be of any use to future visitors, and the answer prob'ly won't do the OP no good no how.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about C++ 

Comment: I think it shows some effort from someone who is a new programmer trying to learn.  It has several logic issues, but at least it might compile.

Answer (score 1):

This is untested because I don't have the declarations of Hand, Deck, and presumably Card, but it should give you an idea of a way to test for different hands.

As noted above, there were several issues in your code like not using `==` to test equality and using commas instead of logical operators (`&&`, `||`) in your if checks.

In general it is better to just have a single Score function that returns a different value for each type of hand (high_card, one_pair, two_pair, three_of_a_kind, flush, etc.) rather than having to test each hand multiple times.  It lets you compare hands easily by their score and greatly reduces the amount of duplicate work you need to do like counting the ranks and suits.  Sorting the hand is also a good idea since it simplifies testing for straights as you can just test for the spread between the ranks of first and last cards once you've eliminated the rest of the scoring hands.

```
bool Hand::isFlush()
{
    for(int i = 1; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        if(cardVector[i].suit != cardVector[0].suit)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

bool Hand::isThreeOfKind() 
{
    //This is 16 because I don't know if your ranks start at 0 or 2
    int counts[16] = {0};
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        ++counts[cardVector[i].rank];
    }
    //This is just to give you an idea of how having single score function
    //can eliminate work.  If you only want to test for 3 of a kind then
    //you don't need the pairs and fours tests and counts
    int num_pairs = 0;
    int num_threes = 0;
    int num_fours = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
    {
        if(counts[i] == 2)
        {
            ++num_pairs;
        }
        else if(counts[i] == 3)
        {
            ++num_threes;
        }
        else if(counts[i] == 4)
        {
            ++num_fours;
        }
    }
    if(num_threes == 1)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: As others said above I did misinterpret the use of the = operator and other uses for the && ||. I rewrote them with the correct use and got rid of the if and else and it is working. Also I started my rank from 2. Thanks for the input!!!!